# Change a button's data attribute and an element inside it after an ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have button with an [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/check-square?s=solid) icon inside and when the user click on that an ajax call is triggered. The desired outcome is this:

```
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-id="someId1" data-meet="1"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></button>
```

When the button's attribute `data-meet="1"` and the user clicks it, then these should apply:

```
$('#btn2').data('meet', '0');
$('#btn2').removeClass("btn-light");
$('#btn2').addClass("btn-primary");
$('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-square").addClass("fa-check-square");
```

if user clicks it again, the attribute should be now 0 `data-meet="0"` and the following should be applied.

```
$('#btn2').data('meet', '1');
$('#btn2').removeClass("btn-primary");
$('#btn2').addClass("btn-light");
$('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-check-square").addClass("fa-square");
```

However, neither the icon is changed,  neither the condition is calculated right in the first click (meet == 1 but the else part is executed..)

Any ideas;

```js
$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
  var msgId = $(this).data("id");
  var meet = $(this).data("meet");
  console.log("meet = " + meet);

  $.ajax({
    url: '#',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      msgId: msgId,
      meet: meet
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("After ajax call");
    
      if (meet === '1') {
        console.log("change icon to checked");

        $('#btn2').data('meet', '0');
        $('#btn2').removeClass("btn-light");
        $('#btn2').addClass("btn-primary");
        $('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-square").addClass("fa-check-square");
      } else {
        console.log("change icon to uncheck");

        $('#btn2').data('meet', '1');
        $('#btn2').removeClass("btn-primary");
        $('#btn2').addClass("btn-light");
        $('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-check-square").addClass("fa-square");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col ml-5">
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-id="someId1" data-meet="1"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "However, neither the icon is changed, neither the condition is calculated right in the first click" - what happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you debug this using your browser's developer console, what does this yield?

Comment: Problem is that the first time you click `meet` is a number. So 1 === '1' is false. so I would do `var meet = +$(this).data("meet");` and then `if (meet === 1)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the + in +$(this).data("meet") worked, please add it as answer to take credit!

Answer (score 0):

`meet` is a number initially, it may be easier to change the checking and assignment to number type,
i.e.

```
if (meet === 1){
    $('#btn2').data('meet', 0);
    $('#btn2').removeClass("btn-light");
    $('#btn2').addClass("btn-primary");
    $('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-square").addClass("fa-check-square");
} else {
    $('#btn2').data('meet', 1);
    $('#btn2').removeClass("btn-primary");
    $('#btn2').addClass("btn-light");
    $('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-check-square").addClass("fa-square");
}
```

```js
$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
  var msgId = $(this).data("id");
  var meet = $(this).data("meet");
  console.log("meet = " + meet);

  $.ajax({
    url: '#',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      msgId: msgId,
      meet: meet
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("After ajax call");
    
      if (meet === 1) {
        console.log("change icon to checked");

        $('#btn2').data('meet', 0);
        $('#btn2').removeClass("btn-light");
        $('#btn2').addClass("btn-primary");
        $('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-square").addClass("fa-check-square");
      } else {
        console.log("change icon to uncheck");

        $('#btn2').data('meet', 1);
        $('#btn2').removeClass("btn-primary");
        $('#btn2').addClass("btn-light");
        $('#btn2').find("i.fas").removeClass("fa-check-square").addClass("fa-square");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col ml-5">
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-id="someId1" data-meet="1"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```